# Fade in Ajax content after it's fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current solution gets some content via AJAX, Inserts it into a DIV then hides it and fade it in.

The issue with that is the content contains images and an iframe, The solutions flickers and the fadeIn doesn't look smooth.

What i'd like to do is to only `fadeIn` after the iframe and pictures are fully loaded.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Loading your content into a wrapper div with `display: none` then fading that in should work.

Comment: @JamWaffles That's what i'm doing, But as i said the fadeIn occurs while the images and the iframes are half shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will wait until all child content has finished loading:

```
$("#wrapperDivID").load(function (){
    // do something, e.g.
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

See [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

In your specific case the following should work:

```
$('#content').load('/echo/html/',data, function() {
  alert('fired');
});
```

Comment: Since the container div is already loaded in the DOM the load event wont properly fire when loading that div with content from an ajax request. See: http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Hy4C8/2/

Comment: See my edit. You'd remove the first .load() and replace the second with above. It has the callback function as the third (optional) parameter.

Comment: You're correct on that part. but now you're using the `load` function as an ajax request and not waiting for the img/iframe/etc elements to fully load. see: http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Hy4C8/3/

Comment: Hmm. All I can think of is to attach individual load events to the elements loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Wrapping the entire ajax response `$(htmlResponse).load(...)` should do the trick as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the duration for fadeIn so that it will take little long.

```
 $("#content").load("getform.php"), function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1500);  // or another bigger number based on your load time
 });
```

If you know what all images are going to be in the page, Preload all those images in the page where you have the div "content", so that you will save some loading time.

Comment: That `fadeIn` parameter is the duration of the effect and not a delay for the effect.

Comment: @subhaze :yea. that's what i meant. Obviously the div will be appeared after that many milliseconds.i will change the language

Comment: OK cool, sorry about that. I thought you meant 'delay' as in an actual delay/setTimeout kinda of way...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$.ajax` to get the HTML you can wrap the resulting HTML like below:

```
$.ajax('some/path/to.html',{
    'success':function(html){
        var result = $(html).load(function(){
            $('#content').fadeIn()
        });
        $('#content').html(result);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Hy4C8/)

Answer (score 0):

another way you can do this:

```
$( "#content" ).fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(this).load( url, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

change the fadeIn and Out times to whatever is good for you.